# Select unique ordered values of several columns in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, columnsorting

I am using a table with a couple of geometries in each row. I would like that each geometries appears only once in my database. I sorted the couple by distance. I succeded to have distinct geom1 or geom2 but never in the same time. The ids are linked to their related geometries.

```
| id1 | id2 | distance|        | id1 | id2 | distance|
|  1  |  2  |    3    |        |  1  |  2  |    3    |
|  2  |  1  |    4    |    ->  |  2  |  1  |    7    |
|  2  |  2  |    7    |
|  1  |  1  |    9    |
```

My table contains more than 2 millions rows, so the performance is an issue.
I taught to create several temp table where I group by the id1 and then id2, collect the missing values and group by again and again... But if anyone has a better idea, It would be amazing.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you choosing which rows to keep?

Comment: For example, I would choose an id1 and choose the closet unused id2

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you are looking for distinct triplets of id1, id2 and distance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2 , distance FROM <table name>;
```

or

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM <table name> GROUP BY id1, id2, distance;
```

Comment: Not exactly, because that would give unique triplet and they all are

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select t1.*
from table t1
where id2 = (select max(t1.id2) from table t2 where t2.id1 = t1.id1);
```